# Azure Change the associated directory 'None'

Tags: azure, directory

When I go into the classic portal, Settings on the left, select my subscription, When I click edit to 'Change the associated directory' I only have 'None' in the drop-down.  I think this s breaking my SQL AD Authentication.  I have a directory set up with users and groups and I can see it and manipulate it in the new portal.  I can't however log in to a SQL instance using AD username/password.

How can I get my directory to show up in the list?

[image: Azure Change the associated directory dialogue.]

Answer (score 0):

That seems like it would be the issue, if you can't see the directory listed and you see 'None' then you need to verify you are an the account administrator of the subscription and global administrator of the directory otherwise you will not be able to associate it with your subscription.

Comment: Hi Martyn, I am the global admin for the subscription and I was using the Directory Admin account, which is the primary account on the subscription.  I still get 'None' in the drop-down.  It doesn't seem to connect my AAD with my subscription in the Classic portal.

Comment: Are you the account administrator (aka service administrator) though? That is different to a co-administrator on the subscription. Check it out at the [Account Center](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions).

Comment: I am the Service Administrator with the account I have been using.  My account has two entries in the Microsoft portals, one personal, and one corporate.  I have seen some articles suggesting that this could be a problem.  Could that be it?

Comment: Yes it could be, which one are you using? I would stick with the corporate one and remove the personal one. I've also seen issues like this with original users of Azure from a couple of years back, those accounts are "special" I'm told, I've only been able to raise a support ticket to have things like this resolved in the past.

Comment: Thanks Martyn.  I can't log in with the corporate one, only the personal one.  I have a support ticket open.